# Inductive step in the induction: $\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\times2$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am trying induction for the following formula:

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\times2$$

I have done the initial step which gives me for $n=1$ for both sites $1+q$

In the inductive step I wrote:
$$(\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i ) \times \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\times2 =\frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\times2 \times \frac {1-q^{n+2}}{1-q}\times2 = 4 \times \frac {-q*q^n - q^2 q^n + 1 + q^3 q^{2n}}{1-q}$$

However, here I am stuck...

I really would appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Where did the $\times 2$ come from?  Why are you expanding lots of multiplication in a sum?

Comment: As @abiessu noted. You're going to have trouble proving this, since it's wrong. It would be correct if you eliminated the $\times 2$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning note:  all operations below assume that $q\ne 1$.  To avoid other pitfalls, also assume that $q\ne 0$.

For induction on a sum, you would use the following process:

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\times2$$

- Show for $n=1$ (or $n=0$, if desired)
- Assume statement is true for an arbitrary $n=k\gt 1$
- Show statement holds for $n=k+1$

For the base case, use $n=1$ as the point where you started.  Then we have:

$$\sum^{1}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{1+1}}{1-q}\times2 \implies 1+q=\frac {(1-q)(1+q)}{1-q}$$

$$=\frac {1-q^2}{1-q}\ne \frac {1-q^2}{1-q}\times 2$$

Already, we have failed to show the required induction.  At this point I would start again, ensuring that your formula is correct.

Continuing forward as if we had succeeded at the base step, we would have the following:

Show that:

$$\sum^{k+1}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{k+2}}{1-q}\times2$$

To do this, we would use

$$\sum^{k}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{k+1}}{1-q}\times2$$

(our assumption step) and add the $k+1$ term to both sides, like so:

$$\sum^{k}_{i=0} q^i + q^{k+1} = \frac {1-q^{k+1}}{1-q}\times2 + q^{k+1}$$

$$\implies \sum^{k+1}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{k+1}}{1-q}\times2+\frac{(1-q)q^{k+1}}{1-q}$$

$$=\frac {2-q^{k+1}-q^{k+2}}{1-q}\ne \frac {1-q^{k+2}}{1-q}\times2$$

The problems we found at the base case continue through the entire induction process and show again that the original formula as stated cannot be correct.

A related form of your formula looks like this in the final steps:

$$\sum^{k+1}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{k+1}}{1-q}+\frac{(1-q)q^{k+1}}{1-q}$$

$$=\frac {1-q^{k+1}+(1-q)q^{k+1}}{1-q}=\frac {1-q^{k+2}}{1-q}$$

Comment: I'd like to see a verification of the base case.

Comment: @RickDecker: added in a way that demonstrates how it does not work.  My goal is to show the OP where the formula is wrong and how the correct formula is generated and is proven.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried it without the 2 at the end. However, for me it works in the inital step. Is this correct?

Comment: @user5414: Perhaps you could detail the steps you took to show that the formula works correctly at the initial step with the $2$ applied.  I don't know how that could work.